# RStudio does not render Plotly plot on new machine

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly, rendering

I bought a new laptop a few days ago (Windows 10) and installed R 4.0.0 and the last RStudio version (Desktop 1.2.5042) on it. Subsequently I ran the rtools40 installer and installed the latest versions of the popular R packages (including ggplot, plotly and so on). Everything seems to work, except for the RStduio viewer pane when trying to render a plotly plot. What happens is that, when I run a minimal example (like this https://plotly.com/r/line-charts/) the view pane is activated, but no plot is rendered. Also no error is raised and the RStudio R session starts draining a lot of CPU capacity, although no code is apparently running (e.g. I can run a plot() and it will be properly displayed in the plot pane).

Now, I've tried downgrading and running RStudio (3.x) from Anaconda - neither worked.

Also - my browser wold not render local plotly plots, bit it would render external plots (like in the example above https://plotly.com/r/line-charts/).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is an issue with R 4.0 and RStudio 1.2.5042 on Windows 10 x64:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6737

I downgraded to R 3.6.1 and RStudio 1.2.5042 and the problem is gone.

RStudio is due to fix the issue with its v1.3-patch.